# hyperledger-fabric getting-started failed to start cli container

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

Anyone run into the error in setting up environment (http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) where the cli container does not come up? I am running on a Xenial (ubuntu 16.04) guest of RHEL 7.3 ... so I stopped firewalld on RHEL (issue I ran into in past with docker-compose) ... but it did not help. Main error is:

[35mpeer0.org2.example.com |[0m [31m2017-05-03 12:45:02.139 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 001[0m Error building images: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
[35mpeer0.org2.example.com |[0m [31m2017-05-03 12:45:02.139 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 002[0m Image Output:
[35mpeer0.org2.example.com |[0m ********************
[35mpeer0.org2.example.com |[0m Step 1/3 : FROM hyperledger/fabric-baseos:x86_64-0.3.0
[35mpeer0.org2.example.com |[0m
[35mpeer0.org2.example.com |[0m ********************
[35mpeer0.org2.example.com |[0m [31m2017-05-03 12:45:02.139 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 003[0m launchAndWaitForRegister failed Error starting container: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
[34mcli |[0m [36m2017-05-03 12:44:41.094 UTC [logging] InitFromViper -> DEBU 001[0m Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'chaincode'

And I am attaching captured output. As I was going thru instructions, it was going almost scary good ... so I guess I was due (will host via github if someone interested).

Comment: Can you paste your error info with a better format, no one want to see this messing logs.

Comment: There is no stderr and here is the stdout ... and the stderr is empty.
https://github.com/MikeC711/hlfv1Problem/blob/master/cli.out